# How can I populate meta fields of a Woocommerce manual order

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I have defined two custom fields for my Woocommerce orders. I used [WooCommerce Admin Custom Order Fields extension](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/woocommerce-admin-custom-order-fields/) to create these two fields.

When I manually create an order (/wp-admin/post-new.php?post_type=shop_order), I can see those fields and I can successfully add data and save the order.

I would, however, like to automatically populate one of those fields in the code. I'm trying to use the following code to do find out the meta key to that custom field so I can use `update_post_meta()` to populate it, but this does not give me anything when I run it:

```
add_action('woocommerce_process_shop_order_meta', 'process_offline_order', 10, 2);
function process_offline_order ($post_id, $post) {
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r(get_post_meta($post_id));
    die();
}
```

The documentation to that extension tells me that I can use something like `get_post_meta($post_id, '_wc_acof_2')` with 2 being the ID of that custom field and I tried that too with no luck. It's not returning anything.

Below is an screen shot of my configuration screen:

[image]

Any idea how I can access/populate those fields and what hook to use if the one I'm using is not correct?

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the configuration screen for these custom fields?

Comment: Andrew, I just added a screenshot. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try to use instead "save_post" action hook this way:

```
// Saving (Updating) or doing an action when submitting
add_action( 'save_post', 'update_order_custom_field_value' );
function update_order_custom_field_value( $post_id ){

    // Only for shop order
    if ( 'shop_order' != $_POST[ 'post_type' ] )
        return $post_id;

    // Checking that is not an autosave
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
        return $post_id;

    // Check the user’s permissions (for 'shop_manager' and 'administrator' user roles)
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_shop_order', $post_id ) && ! current_user_can( 'edit_shop_orders', $post_id ) )
        return $post_id;

    // Updating custom field data
    if( isset( $_POST['wc-admin-custom-order-fields'][2] ) ) {
        // The new value
        $value = 'Green';

        // OR Get an Order meta data value ( HERE REPLACE "meta_key" by the correct metakey slug)
        // $value = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'meta_key', true ); // (use "true" for a string or "false" for an array)

        // Replacing and updating the value
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_wc_acof_2', $value );
    }
}


// Testing output in order edit pages (below billing address):
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'display_order_custom_field_value' );
function display_order_custom_field_value( $order ){
    foreach( get_option( 'wc_admin_custom_order_fields' ) as $id => $field ){
        $value = get_post_meta( $order->get_id(), '_wc_acof_'.$id, true );
        // Define Below the custom field ID to be displayed
        if( $id == 2 && ! empty( $value ) ){
            echo '<p><strong>' . $field['label'] . ':</strong> ' . $value . '</p>';
        }
    }
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Comment: Your code looks very promising, but unfortunately it does not work for me. First of all, it didn't update the custom field value to "Green" as you have it in your code, and secondly, when I dump the `$_POST` request, I don't see `_wc_acof_2` coming through the request.

Comment: Can you add a dump of what the post array looks like?  The field name for the custom post field might not be correct.

Comment: Thank you, I replaced `if( isset( $_POST['_wc_acof_2'] ) ) {` with `if( isset( $_POST['wc-admin-custom-order-fields'][2] ) ) {` and it's now working.

Comment: Excellent, glad to have helped.