# WooCommerce: Update field value before saving the post

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I have an extra custom field (Advanced Custom Fields) in WooCommerce to display some product highlights. These highligts are formatted in HTML like this:

```
<li>Supports thousands of apps</li>
<li>1080p maximum display resolution</li>
<li>Supports both 2.4 Ghz and 5 Ghz Wi-Fi networks</li>
<li>Supports iOS</li>
```

I need them in a format [like this](https://support.google.com/merchants/answer/9216100?hl=en):

```
<g:product_highlight>Supports thousands of apps</g:product_highlight>
<g:product_highlight>1080p maximum display resolution</g:product_highlight>
<g:product_highlight>Supports both 2.4 Ghz and 5 Ghz Wi-Fi networks</g:product_highlight>
<g:product_highlight>Supports iOS</g:product_highlight>
```

Basically I just need to change the tags and save the content in a second meta field.

I found a documentation to [update the value of a specific field](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/update_field/) and to [fire an action when saving a post](https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/acf-save_post/).

My snippet looks like this:

```
add_action('acf/save_post', 'my_acf_save_post', 5);
function my_acf_save_post( $post_id ) {

    // Get previous values.
    $prev_values = get_fields( $post_id );

    // Get submitted values.
    $values = $_POST['acf'];

    // Check if a specific value was updated.
    if( isset($_POST['acf']['product_details_usp']) ) {
        
        $field_key = "product_details_usp_google";
        $value = "some new string";
        update_field( $field_key, $value, $post_id );
        
    }
}
```

My meta field with the data to change is the `product_details_usp`.
I now want to change the data in that field (next step) and save it in `product_details_usp_google`.

But it doesn't work. No data is transfered from one field to the other.
Is there anything wrong with my code?

Comment: Where did you get so far with your debugging? Did you check that it goes into that if branch? Have you checked the return value of update_field?

Comment: I did some debugging and the snippet doesn't seem to work. I try some other ways now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution based on [this answer from LoicTheAztec](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46879675/1788961)

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'update_usp_google_shopping' );
function update_usp_google_shopping( $post_id ){

    // Only for shop order
    if ( 'product' != $_POST[ 'post_type' ] )
        return $post_id;

    // Checking that is not an autosave
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE )
        return $post_id;

    // Check the user’s permissions (for 'shop_manager' and 'administrator' user roles)
    if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_shop_order', $post_id ) && ! current_user_can( 'edit_shop_orders', $post_id ) )
        return $post_id;

    // Updating custom field data
    if( isset( $_POST['acf'] ) ) {
                    
        // The new value
        $value = 'Test';

        // OR Get an Order meta data value ( HERE REPLACE "meta_key" by the correct metakey slug)
        // $value = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'meta_key', true ); // (use "true" for a string or "false" for an array)

        // Replacing and updating the value
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'product_details_usp_google', $value );
    }
}
```

The code adds the Test value to the new custom field.